# Error in browser console XMLHttpRequest.send @ csrf.js:103 wso2carbon

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server

I'm currently working in wso2das. after creation of dashboard when ever i go to design console showing an error of 
https://192.168.2.104:9443/portal/csrf.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I tried to configure web.xml and carbon.xml but unable to fix. Please help me.

Comment: show your error message and code here

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam   Thanks for your reply

Comment: https://192.168.2.104:9443/portal/csrf.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
XMLHttpRequest.send @ csrf.js:103

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam if message is not clear can send screen shot

Comment: csrf.js is used to CSRF protection. I think there's a wrong bath set in the dashboard somewhere. What is the DAS version you are trying this on?

Comment: ws02 Dashboard Server v.2.0.0. I'm trying to use my  own gadget. Dont have problem using of Default gadgets @farasath

Comment: can you try a default gadget and in the design console see where the csrf.js is successfully loaded from?